# How to make gif image appear as splash screen

Tags: android, android-studio, animated-gif

I want to show gif image in my android application as a splash for five seconds(without using webview). If I am using ImageView, and adding Gif to it,  it is not showing as general Image.Please help regarding this.

Comment: Use glide for gif support

Comment: Thanks for responding SilentKiller....Till now I have tried adding gif image as a source to imageView but it is just showing as a Jpg format image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Put   `compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'`

in your build.gradle file as dependency.

2. Put your .gif file in the drawable folder

Call the below method in onCreate of your SplashActivity

```
public void startSplash(){
        Animation fadeout = new AlphaAnimation(1.f, 1.f);
        fadeout.setDuration(2500);
        final View viewToAnimate = gifImageView;
        fadeout.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                gifImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash_screen);//splash_screen is your .gif file
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        });
        gifImageView.startAnimation(fadeout);
    }


 Put the below code in your SplashActivty.xml

     <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />
```

Go to your Project Level build.gradle file and add the below code if its not there

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Or You can also try

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding n9153,
Getting an error...failed to resolve compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error ? Have you added this as gradle dependency ?

Comment: ya it is my gradle dependency ,
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}

Comment: @EED did you add `maven` to your `build.gradle` top dependency.

Comment: Ok.
Is it ok if I add single line "compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+' " in dependencies of build.gradle.
If it is YES , in that case I am getting error, Failed to resolve compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'.
how to get rid of this error.Please help me

Comment: I have done using all those previously . But not resolved

Comment: Mr. n9513, Is it necessary to add any library file for that dependency to be worked?

Comment: Adding the library will make it much simpler. Else you ll have to convert the gif into a byte array and then show as an animation on a Worker thread

Answer (score 1):

Try this for gif view

1. Use the Dependencies

   ```
   compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.17'
   ```
2. Replace Imageview to this XML

   ```
   <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/splashbg"/>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Set a webview as your splash and let the browser to to render the gif. That's all!